# Could not manually create user with devise in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This problem is driving me crazy, I have followed every example written here and nothing happens.

My code is the following:

```
@user = User.new(
          :username => params[:username],
          :email => params[:email],
          :password => params[:password],
          :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation],
          :birth_date => params[:birth_date],
          :gender => params[:gender]
        )
if object = @user.save
  output = "User created"
else
  output = "Error happened"
    ...
```

So, I always get the error message.

In the server I get this output:

```
Started POST "/moiapi/register.json" for 186.70.55.28 at 2014-05-07 02:25:10 -0400
Processing by MoiController#register as JSON
  Parameters: {"username"=>"demo1", "email"=>"demo1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "birth_date"=>"1983-09-11", "gender"=>"M"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'demo1@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('demo1') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 200 OK in 1069ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 460.8ms)
```

As final remarks, the user does not exists and I am passing the password_confirmation parameter, but the .save method is returning me false.

Comment: Try doing `p @user.errors.full_messages` after saving the user to see where validations failed.

Comment: many causes why when devise rollback, one that is not appropriate or lack of character passwords, set its default devise long-character password between 8 to 128 characters, take a look on `config/initializer/devise.rb`